# Are Intel Wireless notebook antennas interchangeable?

Tags: wireless-networking, antenna

My notebook came with a Intel Wireless link N 5100 and I would like to upgrade to a Intel Wireless AC 7260 and would like to know if the antennas I already have will work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember where I read it to post a link but I have read that it will work as long as the preexisting antennas are from a dual band card they will work with the AC cards.